# Error: Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'TreeBagger'

Tags: matlab, undefined-function

I have trained a random forest for binary classification via `TreeBagger`:

```
Mdl = TreeBagger(trees, X1, y1, 'NumPredictorsToSample', features, ...
                 'OOBPrediction', 'on', 'Method', 'classification', 'OOBVarImp', 'on');
```

I am trying to return the [error (misclassification probability)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/treebagger.error.html) of the training set (`X1`):

```
train_error = error(Mdl, X1, y1)
```

However, I receive this error message:

```
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'TreeBagger'.
```

Note that I am not looking for the out-of-bag error; I have already obtained that without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd bet real-world currency you named a variable `error`, and MATLAB is trying to index that variable using `Mdl`. However, `Mdl` can't be used as an index since it doesn't have a [`subsindex` method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subsindex.html) defined, as the error message states. Type the following then retry your code:

```
clear error
```

You generally shouldn't give a variable the same name as an existing function (i.e. "shadowing"). The [function precedence order](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html) documentation has this to say:

> If you create a variable with the same name as a function, MATLAB cannot run that function until you clear the variable from memory.

Comment: I think you were right. I had thought the same thing, and subsequently removed all items from the workspace but without much luck. However after restarting Matlab it worked.

Many thanks!